# railsでhashのvalueにimage_tagを入れる方法は？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Railsを使って、hashのvalueにimage_tagを入れる方法はありますでしょうか？

app/の下にview_objects/を作ってその中にviewに関するロジックをclassごとにいれています。
できるだけviewにロジックを書き込まないようにするためです。
view_objects/内のクラスで作ったインスタンス変数（hash型）をview内で展開して表示させています。

```
# view_objects/article_view.rb
class ArticleView
  attr_reader :header

  def initialize(data)
    @header = { 
      title: data.title,
      image: '= image_tag ' + data.img
    }
  end
end


# view/article/index.html.slim

 table.table
 - @article_view.header.each do |key, value|
   tr
     td = key
     td = value
```

headerのハッシュ型の中には画像リンクが入っているのですが、どうしてもリンク元の画像が参照されずに、そのURLだけが文字列で記載されてしまいます。
どうすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

一般的に View 以外に具体的なタグを入れるのは良いスタイルとはいえませんが、どうしてもというのであれば、以下のように `content_tag` を使うことができます。

```
class ArticleView
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  attr_reader :header

  def initialize(data)
    @header = { 
      title: data.title,
      image: content_tag(:img, "", :src => data.img),
    }
  end
end
```

Partial view、Helper、デコレータ (DraperやActiveDecoratorなどの非標準機能) の利用も検討してみてください。

Comment: できました。ありがとうございます！